# Remove iframe security check for 404 pages

Tags: bug, status-declined, flair, 404-not-found

I can't visit the website http://fredrikholmstrom.com/ because the page contains Stack Overflow flair embedded in an `iframe`:
https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/17809.html?theme=dark

The flair URL leads to a 404 page, which in turn pops up a **modal dialog**:

> "For security reasons, framing is not allowed; click OK to remove the frames."

This makes the site unusable.

My suggestion is to remove the `iframe` check on 404 pages.

Comment: I guess support for HTML flair has finally been discontinued. Long live [image-based flair](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/flair-now-even-flairier/)!

Answer (score 1):

`<iframe>` flair is deprecated.

Please switch to the new image based flair:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/flair-now-even-flairier/

Comment: I did months ago, but http://fredrikholmstrom.com/ issn't my site. First encouraging users to embed a iframe, and then redirecting their visitors to your site is just *not nice*.

Comment: @bob I get "error creating a database connection" going to that site right now, so I think it has a number of issues..